# API call my ajax success function never get called

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to make an api call using &.ajax, when I use jsonp property outside my project folder the success function never get called but if I make the call directly from my  project folder using json the success function does get called.

Please, does anybody know why the success function never gets called when using jsonp. My code is below.

```
var mysuccess= function (resp) {
                              alert("success");
                          };
                var mystatus=         {
                         200: function (rsp) {
                            alert(JSON.stringify(rsp));
                        }
                       };
                 var myerror=function (resp) {
                              alert("error");
                          };
              function GetQuestion() {
                var url1="http://localhost:50107/api/security/Question"
                  $.ajax({ url:url1,
                      type: 'GET',
                      dataType: 'jsonp',
                      cache: false,
                      jsonp: '$callback',
                      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                      statusCode:mystatus, 
                      success:mysuccess,
                      error: myerror,
                  });
              };
```

Comment: do you get any console errors when the success method is not called ?

Comment: @Yasser i get alert when myerror callback function is called.

Comment: @JED can you provide the error response from the server i.e. status code and message. With a fiddler trace of the request if possible.

Comment: ok so your error function is called, try this `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);` and find out what is your error.
}

Comment: @Yasser when do this  alert(textStatus, errorThrown); i got parsererror

Comment: use `console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);` and read errors in console. open console by pressing F12.